# Android Studio problem: NEGOTIATE authentication error: No valid credentials provided

Tags: android-studio, kerberos, credentials

I'm working in Android Studio with KMM and into network domain controller.
Actually I'm stuck with this error.
I have already set PROXY settings in Android Studio IDE...
Any idea to solve?

ERROR:
 `NEGOTIATE authentication error: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt))`

I tried to set proxy settings in IDE but nothing it changes...

Answer (score 0):

I solved changing the file gradle.properties in my local home with proxy variables...

```properties
#Fri Jan 27 10:08:47 CEST 2022
artifactory_user=myUsername
systemProp.http.proxyPort=8080
artifactory_contextUrl=http\://artifact-02.dmz.mydomain.org\:8082/artifactory
systemProp.http.proxyUser=myDomain/myUsername
systemProp.https.proxyPassword=
systemProp.http.proxyHost=proxy.italia.mydomain.org
systemProp.https.proxyUser=myDomain/myUsername
systemProp.http.auth.ntlm.domain=myDomain
systemProp.https.proxyHost=proxy.italia.myDomain.org
systemProp.https.proxyPort=8080
artifactory_password=myArtifactoryPassword
systemProp.https.auth.ntlm.domain=myDomain
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=
systemProp.https.nonProxyHosts=*.myDomain.org
systemProp.http.nonProxyHosts=*.myDomain.org
```